# How to position "SecurityPanel" in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, security, flex3

In my application, I want to set a fixed position for the SecurityPanel.
Is there any way to set the x and y postion for SecurityPanel?

Currently I use:

```
security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.PRIVACY);
```

This shows the pop up in the centre of the app but I want to define some value for positioning.

Answer (score 0):

The `Security.showSettings()` doesn't return a reference to the panel that gets popped up, so I don't believe it's possible to move it, change it or affect it in any way.

This is probably since Adobe doesn't want anyone messing around with the security settings panel itself since that could be considered a security risk.

Answer (score -1):

use this:
`Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.SETTINGS_MANAGER)`
this will show security panel in a new window

Comment: This question does not ask about how to open the security panel in a new window but rather asks specifically how to set its position. The answer you have supplied would have been better suited toward a question asking how to show the security panel specifically in a new window.